# How implement a BottomSheet in android application?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am implementing a bottom sheet inside my application using Material Design. When running the app, it crashes and returns this error:

```
2019-07-28 13:28:29.774 7520-7520/com.thompson.bottomsheetdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.thompson.bottomsheetdemo, PID: 7520
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thompson.bottomsheetdemo/com.thompson.bottomsheetdemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37 in com.thompson.bottomsheetdemo:layout/activity_main: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3407)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:933)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37 in com.thompson.bottomsheetdemo:layout/activity_main: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:632)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:2863)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:1714)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:112)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1125)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:545)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.thompson.bottomsheetdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3407)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:933)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:630)
2019-07-28 13:28:29.775 7520-7520/com.thompson.bottomsheetdemo E/AndroidRuntime:    ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior.createShapeValueAnimator(BottomSheetBehavior.java:1052)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior.<init>(BottomSheetBehavior.java:255)
            ... 29 more
```

I thought this error was caused by not defining the layout_behavior correclty, but I have the layout_behavior defined as:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

inside the MaterialTextView component. This component is what I want to use for the BottomSheet.

The following is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_expand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Expand"/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_collapse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Collapse"/>
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_state"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="State"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="This is a bottom sheet\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
             Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
              nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
               Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut,
             imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
              Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula,
               porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
                Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet."
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="55dp"
            >


    </com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.thompson.bottomsheetdemo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
import com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<MaterialTextView>
    private lateinit var mTextViewState: MaterialTextView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bottomSheet = findViewById<MaterialTextView>(R.id.bottom_sheet)

        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        mTextViewState = findViewById(R.id.text_view_state)

        val buttonExpand = findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.button_expand)
        val buttonCollapse = findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.button_collapse)

        buttonExpand.setOnClickListener{
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }

        buttonCollapse.setOnClickListener{
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
        }

        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object: BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(){
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                when(newState){
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> mTextViewState.text = "Collapsed"

                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> mTextViewState.text = "Expanded"

                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING -> mTextViewState.text = "Dragging"

                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED -> mTextViewState.text = "Half Expanded"

                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> mTextViewState.text = "Hidden"

                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> mTextViewState.text = "Settling"

                }
            }

            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.thompson.bottomsheetdemo"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Why are you using material library in stable and alpha version at the same time?

Comment: @blackr4y Oops. I meant to delete the 1.0.0 version. Good catch